# How to use apprequest for send or askfor using OpenGraph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Facebook Unity SDK to implement a sample gift module in my game.I am using the method:

```
**public static void AppRequest(
string message,
OGActionType actionType,
*string objectId*,
string[] to,
string data = "",
string title = "",
FacebookDelegate callback = null)**
```

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2

AS the OGAction type refres to the action like askfor or send,the next arguement is object_id which i unable to get properly.

Can anyone tell do the object will be created in the app itself or it must be created in the opengraph section of my app registerd on facebook?Do i need my own sever for this?

I just need to send an item and and recieve it at the reciever's end.Please tell me where i am wrong or what i should i do to get it properly?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

1- On the "Tools & Support" section in the Developers' page, open "Object Browser".

2- Set the "App" and "Object Owner" section to your App.

3- Click "New Object".

4- A new object will be created and you can copy its id in the AppRequest parameters.

I don't know if there is an easier or better way to do it but, so far, I have been getting requests without issues.

Cheers!